# You have treated me well vs You treated me well

Tags: have

Trying to write a short goodbye message to my current workplace.

**Thanks, `company`. You treated me well. My stay wasn't that long, but I will never forget all the great memories.**

In this phrase, should I say

You treated me well or You have treated me well?

Also, does the phrase itself look fine?

Comment: Both read well. I doubt that a definitive answer is possible. The first states what happened. The second describes that it has happened.

Comment: Would you say the sentence itself is fine?

Comment: I suggest you replace “phrase” by “message”. Your question is about the choice of a sentence in a group of three sentences. It is not about a “phrase”, which is a group of words normally forming part of a sentence or clause. My first comment was about the second of your sentences,  both of which read well. I also believe the whole set of sentences to read well, whichever second sentence you use.